# Is this an accurate simulation of a further south Australia with a filled lake Eyre?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, climate, humidity

[image]

I created this climate map based on a simplified Koppen Climate Classification map (shown below). In this scenario Australia is moved 10 degrees of latitude further south and the Lake Eyre basin is filled (shown in map.) Is this an accurate representation of the resulting climate?
[image]

Comment: Can you perhaps show us the Koppen map you're working from (if there is one)... your climate classification terms don't seem to match most typical [Koppen letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification)? Words like temperate and subtropical may well mean vastly different things in our minds! Looks maybe like you're using names more like [the Trewatha system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trewartha_climate_classification), especially with the F category? I haven't been able to find a map with your specific categories, and we'd need to start from a common understanding

Comment: @JeopardyTempest I edited the question and added the map I used

Comment: It's probably impossible to say what the climate would look like if you moved Australia ten degrees further south. It would have a major effect on ocean circulation, probably restricting the Antarctic Circumpolar Current and maybe reopening the Indonesian Seaway amongst other things. Both of these are known to have had pretty major effects on the climate in the past.

Comment: @bon I thought about the Indonesian Seaway problem, so I added a shallow ridge of Islands to the north of Queensland. These islands are fairly large and the space between them is shallow water and coral reef, is that enough to close the Indonesian Seaway?

Comment: Probably. I'm not an oceanographer though.